Proof for result of limits of the form $1^{\infty}$ leading to $e$
I would like to prove the following standard result for limits of the form $1^{\infty}$ from Agarwal:

$\color {blue} {\text{If}}$ $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=\infty$
$\color {blue} {\text{Then}}$ $\lim_{x\to a}
 f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-1)g(x)}$

I know that
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to a} g(x) ln(f(x))}$$
Using the hint, the Macluarin expansion is:
$$ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+...$$
Hence, the approximation is to drop the terms for $x^2$ and beyond.
But what is the justification to use this approximation to make the expression into an exact formula?
Also, what books will cover these kinds of results? Thomas doesn't.
Note: I found videoes that show the derivation step by step using the:

Limit definition of e
Series expansion of ln $x$


It is better to stick to well known limit theorems (algebra of limits, substitution law, squeeze theorem) and use them along with a set of standard limit formulas designed to handle various kinds of elementary functions.
In particular the result in question is a combination of algebra of limits, substitution law, a standard limit and continuity of exponential function. I show it below with more details. First let us make the statement of the theorem a bit more precise.
Theorem: If $f(x) \to 1$ and $f(x) \neq 1$ and $g(x) \to\infty$ and $g(x) (f(x) - 1)\to L$ as $x\to a$ then $f(x) ^{g(x)} \to e^L$ as $x\to a$.
Here we can also have $L$ replaced by $\infty$ (or $-\infty$) in which case $e^L$ is to be replaced by $\infty$ (or $0$). Further the limit operation $x\to a$ can be replaced by $x\to \infty$ or $x\to-\infty$.
To prove the theorem we make use of the limit formula $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log x} {x-1}=1\tag{1}$$ Using this limit formula and rule of substitution we get $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{\log f(x)} {f(x) - 1}=1\tag{2}$$ (here we substitute/replace $x$ with $f(x) $ in equation $(1)$ and this is valid because $f(x) \to 1$ and $f(x) \neq 1$).
Next consider the expression $$g(x) \log f(x) $$ which can be rewritten as $$g(x) (f(x) - 1)\cdot\frac{\log f(x)} {f(x) - 1}$$ which tends to $L\cdot 1=L$ using $(2)$ and given hypotheses. Using continuity of the exponential function we can now say that $e^{g(x) \log f(x)} \to e^L$ ie $f(x) ^{g(x)} \to e^L$. Note that here we have used the substitution law as applicable to continuous functions.
You should also observe that the proof makes no use of the hypotheses $g(x) \to\infty$ and it is thus not necessary.

I get your proof. From an exam point of view, what result(s) would you recommend memorizing?

@Starlight: You should be familiar with limit laws, standard limit formulas (like equation $(1)$ in my answer), l'Hospital rule, and some Taylor series for trig, exponential and logarithmic functions. However for typical/competitive exam problems usually limit laws and limit formulas suffice.

@Starlight: more important however is to know how to use limit formulas like $(1)$. Thus whenever you see a log expression of the form $\log f(x) $ where $f(x) \to 1$ then utilize this formula by dividing multiplying by $f(x) - 1$. Similarly you should understand when and how to use $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x) /x=1$. Whenever you see something like $\sin f(x) $ where $f(x) \to 0$ then you can try using this limit

MacLaurin expansion up to the linear term means actually:
$$\ln(1+x) = x+ o(x) \text{ where } \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{o(x)}x = 0$$
Now, you apply this:
$$g(x)\ln(1+(f(x)-1)) = g(x)\left[f(x)-1 + o(f(x)-1)\right]$$

So the o(f(x)-1) part does not matter? That is what I am confused about. Why does it not matter.

@starlight
If this is not clear to you, you should study Taylor polynomials and their remainders.
And why don't you apply the limit $x\to 0$ to above expression and see for yourself what happens?
